# Authorized App Script needs to be requthorized

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the same (unverified) app script for multiple (around 200) spreadsheets. For each spreadsheet I authorized the script.

Though after a few days it seems like some spreadsheets just loose the authentication and need to be reauthorized.

Can anyone explain why that happens?

Answer (score 1):

This is a recent bug in Google Sheets. If you are logged into multiple Google accounts at the same time, some scripts bound to Google Sheets may require authorization.

However, if you open the same Google Sheet in incognito mode and log into a single Google account, the authorization may not be required.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any edits to the script? That resets the authorization requirement I believe.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using the same (unverified) app script

When running a Google security check-up these will appear as **unverified third party apps** that you are giving access and if you do not recognize the script name you might be inclined to remove access.

You are an 'unverified third party' even though you wrote the script and own the properties being accessed, a problem when Security checks are done.

As I wrote it and I am the only one that has access to it and it only has access to my properties, I don't know why I would be considered unverified much less a third party.